# bind shared_from_this the memory will not be released

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, boost, memory-leaks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

class A: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
    typedef boost::function<int()> GET;
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A::A() " << this << std::endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "A::~A()" << this <<std::endl;
    }

    void set()
    {
        myget=boost::bind(&A::get, shared_from_this()); 
    }
```

Here is the problem: it will not be released when I bind it with with shared_from_this(). But if I bind it with this (boost::bind(&A::get, this)), the instance will be released.

```
    int getI()
    {
        myget();
    }
    inline int get()
    {
        return 1;
    }
private:
    GET myget;
};

void test()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a(new A);
    a->set();
    a->getI();
}

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: why the instance of A is never released even if the program have been shut down?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `myget` variable prevents the destructor from ever running.

So you can't even do

```
~A() { 
    std::cout << "A::~A()" << this << std::endl; 
    myget = {}; 
}
```

This is what weak-pointers have been invented for. In this particular case though, you could simply use `this` as there is no way that `myget` can be accessed after the lifetime of A

Comment: Hi sehe, Many thanks for your answer.  The root cause that I store the share pointer into the internal of it own instance, and it caused the shared pointer never be destoryed by itself.